# How can I display custom fields value from attachment media?

Tags: attachments

I have created the follow code in functions.php to add custom fields to attachments media library. Data saves as well, but I can't get data to display into the template file. Any suggestion??

Thanks!

```
        /**
         * Add custom field to media
        */
        function mytheme_attachment_fields( $fields, $post ) {

            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'title_en', true);
            $fields['title_en'] = array(
                'label' => 'Título (EN)',
                'input' => 'text',
                'value' => $meta,
                'show_in_edit' => true,
            );

            $meta_two = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'description_en', true);
            $fields['description_en'] = array(
                'label' => 'Descripción (EN)',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'value' => $meta_two,
                'show_in_edit' => true,
            );    

            $meta_three = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'title_es', true);
            $fields['title_es'] = array(
                'label' => 'Título (ES)',
                'input' => 'text',
                'value' => $meta_three,
                'show_in_edit' => true,
            );    

            $meta_four = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'description_es', true);
            $fields['description_es'] = array(
                'label' => 'Descripción (ES)',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'value' => $meta_four,
                'show_in_edit' => true,
            );


            return $fields;         
        }
        add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'mytheme_attachment_fields', 10, 2 );

        /**
         * Update custom field on save
        */
        function mytheme_update_attachment_meta($attachment){
            global $post;
              update_post_meta($post->ID, 'title_en', $attachment['attachments'][$post->ID]['title_en']);
              update_post_meta($post->ID, 'description_en', $attachment['attachments'][$post->ID]['description_en']);
              update_post_meta($post->ID, 'title_es', $attachment['attachments'][$post->ID]['title_es']); 
              update_post_meta($post->ID, 'description_es', $attachment['attachments'][$post->ID]['description_es']);  
            return $attachment;
        }
        add_filter( 'edit_attachment', 'mytheme_update_attachment_meta', 4);

        /**
         * Update custom field via ajax
        */
        function mytheme_media_xtra_fields() {
            $post_id = $_POST['id'];
            $meta = $_POST['attachments'][$post_id ]['title_en'];
              update_post_meta($post_id , 'title_en', $meta);
            $meta_two = $_POST['attachments'][$post_id ]['description_en'];
              update_post_meta($post_id , 'description_en', $meta_two); 
            $meta_three = $_POST['attachments'][$post_id ]['title_es'];
              update_post_meta($post_id , 'title_es', $meta_three);
            $meta_four = $_POST['attachments'][$post_id ]['description_es'];
              update_post_meta($post_id , 'description_es', $meta_four); 
            clean_post_cache($post_id);
        }
        add_action('wp_ajax_save-attachment-compat', 'mytheme_media_xtra_fields', 0, 1);
```

Comment: This is a side note, but I just wanted to add that the code for `mytheme_update_attachment_meta()` is not correct. (this is the code that fires when using the non ajax Edit Media screen. `edit_attachment` is an action, not a filter, and it takes one parameter, `$post_id`. I've posted a modified version of the code above in this answer which addresses these concerns: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256463/how-to-save-custom-fields-for-attachments

Answer (score 3):

Use these:

```
get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_title_en', true);
get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_description_en', true);
get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_title_es', true);
get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_description_es', true);
```

See if you need to use the _ prefix:
[Creating Custom Fields for Attachments in Wordpress](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-custom-fields-for-attachments-in-wordpress--net-13076)

Also: [Function Reference/get post meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: @PedroSalusso Please accept the answer so that the question is marked as resolved.  It helps us keep the site tidy.  Thanks.