# How to save custom fields for attachments

Tags: custom-field, attachments, media-library

I have added a custom field "Buy Now" link on media edit page but I am not able to save that data like other post types. Is there any other hook which is triggered after add/edit/update media/attachment?

I am using this function:

```
function update_attachment_extra_info( $post_id ) {

   // code to update data


}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_attachment_extra_info' );
```

But this hook is not triggered.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and include the code that adds the *Buy Now* field?

Comment: Actually, I am using save_post  hook but when I try to update , this hook was not called.

Comment: The hooks `attachment_fields_to_edit`, `edit_attachment`, and `wp_ajax_save-attachment-compat` are what you'll need. The code from this question works, and can easily be adapted: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180092/how-can-i-display-custom-fields-value-from-attachment-media

Comment: Happy to help! I reviewed the code from the question I linked a bit closer and found that the non-ajax part was not correct, so I added the revised code as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example that adds a custom media field named *Buy Now*. This example saves the value of the custom field on the media overlay screen via ajax, as well as the media edit screen (non ajax).

Edit: Added nonce check and sanitization.

```
/**
 * Add custom field to media.
 */
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'wpse256463_attachment_fields', 10, 2 );
function wpse256463_attachment_fields( $fields, $post ) {
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'buy_now', true );

    $fields['buy_now'] = [
      'label'        => __( 'Buy Now', 'text-domain' ),
      'input'        => 'text',
      'value'        => $meta,
      'show_in_edit' => true,
      'extra_rows'   => [
        'nonce' => wp_nonce_field(
          'update_attachment_buy_now', // Action.
          'nonce_attachment_buy_now', // Nonce name.
          true, // Output referer?
          false // Echo?
        ),
      ],
    ];

    return $fields;
}

/**
 * Update custom field within media overlay (via ajax).
 */
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save-attachment-compat', 'wpse256463_media_fields', 0, 1 );
function wpse256463_media_fields() {
  $nonce = $_REQUEST['nonce_attachment_buy_now'] ?? false;

  // Bail if the nonce check fails.
  if ( empty( $nonce ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'update_attachment_buy_now' ) ) {
    return;
  }

  // Bail if the post ID is empty.
  $post_id = intval( $_POST['id'] );
  if ( empty( $post_id ) ) {
    return;
  }

  // Update the post.
  $meta = $_POST['attachments'][ $post_id ]['buy_now'] ?? '';
  $meta = wp_kses_post( $meta );
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'buy_now', $meta );

  clean_post_cache( $post_id );
}

/**
 * Update media custom field from edit media page (non ajax).
 */
add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'wpse256463_update_attachment_meta', 1 );
function wpse256463_update_attachment_meta( $post_id ) {
  $nonce = $_REQUEST['nonce_attachment_buy_now'] ?? false;

  // Bail if the nonce check fails.
  if ( empty( $nonce ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'update_attachment_buy_now' ) ) {
    return;
  }

  $buy_now = isset( $_POST['attachments'][ $post_id ]['buy_now'] )
    ? wp_kses_post( $_POST['attachments'][ $post_id ]['buy_now'] )
    : false;

  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'buy_now', $buy_now );

  return;
}
```

Comment: thanks it saves my day!

Comment: That is working great. I was wondering how can I approach checking nonce for those two actions. I know how to check it when I created it, but this one is something that WP created.

Comment: @ChrisCynarski I added a nonce to the field and checks when saving for both methods. Also added sanitization. I wasn't able to figure out how to successfully verify the nonce sent by WP when saving the fields, so I added my own which I think might be the best way to go here anyway.